# Find text in any array's items

Tags: sql, json, postgresql-9.5

Column states has type jsonb

Example:

```
[{
        "dt": "2020-12-18T16:19:45.378+00:00",
        "id": "confirmed"
    },
    {
        "dt": "2020-12-16T12:11:45.210+00:00",
        "id": "delivery"
    },
    {
        "dt": "2020-12-16T11:25:08.444+00:00",
        "id": "new"

    }
]
```

If I want to find is first item's in array **id = confirmed**

I use this

```
select id, states from my_table where states->0->>'id' = 'confirmed'
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But... I need is check is exist **id = confirmed** in ANY array's items.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains operator `@>`

```
select id, states 
from my_table 
where states @> '[{"id": "confirmed"}]'
```